# Making a backend API call from a service

Tags: android, performance, api, service, geolocation

I have a service that runs in both foreground and background to get the user location at all times, I simply use a LocalBroadCastManager to send the location from the foreground to an activity in my application and then start my API call.

How to achieve the same when the service is running in the background or when the application is closed.

The service:

```
public class LocationService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = "LocationService";
    private LocationManager mLocationManager = null;
    private static final int LOCATION_INTERVAL = 0;
    private static final float LOCATION_DISTANCE = 1000f;
    private HandlerThread mHandlerThread;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private final IBinder mBinder = new MyLocalBinder();
    Location mLastLocation;

    private class LocationListener implements android.location.LocationListener
    {


        public LocationListener(String provider)
        {
            Helper.showLog(TAG, "LocationListener " + provider);
            mLastLocation = new Location(provider);

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
        {
            Helper.showLog(TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location);
            mLastLocation.set(location);
            sendBroadcast();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
        {
            Helper.showLog(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
        {
            Helper.showLog(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: " + provider);
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
        {
            Helper.showLog(TAG, "onStatusChanged: " + provider);
        }
    }

    LocationListener[] mLocationListeners = new LocationListener[] {
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER),
            new LocationListener(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)
    };

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        mHandlerThread = new HandlerThread("LocalServiceThread");
        mHandlerThread.start();
        mHandler = new Handler(mHandlerThread.getLooper());
        initializeLocationManager();
        try {

            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "network provider does not exist, " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        try {
            mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                    LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, LOCATION_INTERVAL, LOCATION_DISTANCE,
                    mLocationListeners[0]);
        } catch (java.lang.SecurityException ex) {
            Log.i(TAG, "fail to request location update, ignore", ex);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Log.d(TAG, "gps provider does not exist " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        sendBroadcast();
    }
    public void postRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
        mHandler.post(runnable);
    }

    public class MyLocalBinder extends Binder {
        public LocationService getService() {
            return LocationService.this;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        Helper.showLog(TAG, "onDestroy");
        super.onDestroy();
        if (mLocationManager != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < mLocationListeners.length; i++) {
                try {
                    mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListeners[i]);
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "fail to remove location listeners, ignore", ex);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void initializeLocationManager() {
        Helper.showLog(TAG, "initializeLocationManager");
        if (mLocationManager == null) {
            mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        }
    }

 private void sendBroadcast(){
     Intent intent = new Intent ("message"); //put the same message as in the filter you used in the activity when registering the receiver
     intent.putExtra("latitude",mLastLocation.getLatitude() );
     intent.putExtra("longitude",mLastLocation.getLongitude() );

 LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(intent);
 }

}
```